# sed delete not working with cat variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file named test-domain, the contents of which contain the line *100.am*.

When I do this, the line with 100.am is deleted from the test-domain file, as expected:

```
for x in $(echo 100.am); do sed -i "/$x/d" test-domain; done
```

However, if instead of *echo 100.am*, I read each line from a file named unwanted-lines, it does NOT work.

```
for x in $(cat unwanted-lines); do sed -i "/$x/d" test-domain; done
```

This is even if the only contents of unwanted-lines is one line, with the exact contents *100.am*.

Does anyone know why sed delete line works if you use *echo* in your variable, but not if you use *cat*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know why sed delete line works if you use echo in your
>   variable, but not if you use cat?

I believe that your file containing *unwanted lines* contains `CR+LF` line endings due to which it doesn't work when you use the file.  You could strip the CR in your loop:

```
for x in $(cat unwanted-lines); do x="${x//$'\r'}"; sed -i "/$x/d" test-domain; done
```

Comment: `for x in $(cat ...)` is terrible, especially if there are `*` in the file `unwanted-lines`! you'll then have bash's globing interfere. Very, very messy. Besides, this only works for files with one word per line.

Comment: Changed the answer to this - the actual issue was carriage returns (I had copied a file from Windows). So stripping like that worked, but also for x in $(cat  unwanted-urls | dos2unix); do sed -i "\~$x~d" test-domains; done
 worked.

Answer (score 5):

```
fgrep -v -f unwanted-lines test-domain > /tmp/Buffer
mv /tmp/Buffer test-domain
```

sed is not interesting in this case due to multiple call in shell (poor efficiency and lot of ressources used). The way to still use sed is to preload line to delete, and make a search base on this preloaded info but very heavy compare to fgrep in this case

Comment: Thanks very much, that works brilliantly and seems much more efficient and neater than using sed here, as you said. The only thing was, I needed to run dos2unix on the unwanted-urls file first. Much faster executing fgrep though than sed.

Answer (score 1):

One better strategy than yours would be to use a genuine editor, e.g., `ed`, as so:

```
ed -s test-domain < <(
    shopt -s extglob
    while IFS= read -r l; do
        [[ $l = *([[:space:]]) ]] && continue
        l=${l//./\\.}
        echo "g/$l/d"
    done < unwanted-lines
    echo "wq"
)
```

**Caveat.** You must make sure that the file `unwanted-lines` doesn't contain any character that could clash with `ed`'s regexps and commands. I have already included a match for a period (i.e., replace `.` with `\.`).

This method is quite efficient, as you're not forking so many times on `sed`, writing temp files, renaming them, etc.

Another possibility would be to use `grep`, but then you won't have the *editing* option `ed` offers.

**Remark.** `ed` is the standard editor.

Comment: Thanks for that, very interesting one! I'll go with fgrep for my particular issue right now.

Answer (score -1):

why not just applying the sed command on your file?

`sed -i '/.*100\.am/d' your_file`

Comment: doesn't address the problem at all.